# Should a Set contain only immutable elements?

Tags: java

I have a `Set` of elements of type `A`.

Does my code smell, if I modify elements contained in the Set (considering the fact, that this modification might change the identity of any `a`)?

Comment: It doesn't just smell. It breaks.

Comment: depends on which fields are used to calculate hashCode/ equals and which fields are modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time a set should only contain immutables.

From [the JavaDoc of the Set interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: **Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements**. The behavior of a set **is not specified** if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

Emphasis mine.

If you are able to modify elements without affecting `equals()` I would strongly reconsider whether your implementation of equals is correct.

Comment: The implementation of `equals()` is _correct_ if it does not surprise any programmer who writes code that calls it.  (That includes not surprising any programmer who will use members of your class in a `Set`.)  If you are the only person who will ever write code that uses your class, then your opinion is the only one that matters.  If, on the other hand, you intend for your code to be re-used by others, then you might want to think harder about what those others will expect `equals()` to mean.

Comment: I disagree. I believe any implementation of `equals` should compare every field. This is the *only* implementation that will be universally understood. If you want to compare a subset of an object's fields, you should add another sensibly named method: `isSamePlaceAs()`, `isSameSizeAs()` etc.

Answer (score 3):

One issue, for example, is that if you add an `A a` to a set, then mutate `a` in a way that changes its hashcode, there is a chance that `set.contains(a)` will return false.

Trivial example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Set<A> set = new HashSet<> ();
  A a = new A(1);
  set.add(a);
  System.out.println(set.contains(a)); //true
  a.i = 2;
  System.out.println(set.contains(a)); //false
}

static class A {
  int i;
  public A(int i) { this.i = i; }
  @Override public int hashCode() { return i; }
}
```

Comment: One assumes that your example assumes a corresponding implementation of `equals` even though you don't show it.

Comment: @LewBloch It is not required for this example to work, but yes in general you would also override `equals`.

Comment: How will a `Set` find the item if the `equals` method returns the wrong answer? Yes, it is required for this example to work. Remember, hashed collections use both `hashCode` and `equals`. If they aren't consistent, the code breaks. In effect, you are claiming that broken code is acceptable.

Comment: @LewBloch Not really, HashSet first uses the hashcode to find the correct bucket, then it uses equals to find the correct element within the bucket. In the example, I change the bucket of the element from 1 to 2, so the hashset searches in bucket 2, finds nothing, and never uses equals. Admittedly this is an edge case and I agree that equals should be consistent with hashcode in 99% of the situations.

Comment: @LewBloch If you run the example, you will see the output as true and false.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can break a `Set` by modifying the mutable elements inside, immutable is definitely *preferred*.

Answer (score 0):

It most probably smells, because if a field is modified that is also used to calculate the hashCode, the `Set` breaks.

Modifications to elements in a `Set` therefore can break a `Set`.

In contrast, modifications to elements in a `List` will never break that List.

Trivial example (taken and extended from assylias answer)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<A> set = new HashSet<>();
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
    A a = new A(1);
    set.add(a);
    list.add(a);
    System.out.println(set.contains(a)); // true
    System.out.println(list.contains(a)); // true
    a.i = 2;
    System.out.println(set.contains(a)); // false
    System.out.println(list.contains(a)); // true
    }

    static class A {
    int i;

    public A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
        return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof A)) {
        return false;
        }
        A other = (A) obj;
        if (i != other.i) {
        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: One assumes that your example assumes a corresponding implementation of `equals` even though you don't show it

Comment: Thanks Lew, fixed.

Comment: Suggested idiom: `return i == other.i`. It is somewhat redundant to use a `boolean` in an `if` to determine a `boolean`.